# Vimeo Pro Video Upload Authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

We are launching a new video streaming business and believe Vimeo Pro is the product to use. But, before purchasing we need help figuring out how to navigate the video upload authentication process through a Ruby on Rails application.

1. We are attempting to interact/authenticate on behalf of the user/member.
2. We are a multi-user site so hard coding a user access token won't work, unless it can be our access token. Can this be done?
3. The users are not the app owner they are site members.
4. We will be running a "channel" along with storage, so that the general public can view videos.

We are following the official getting started API document section “Upload API”: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload

What we have found is when a user uploads videos through our application, they get redirected to the Vimeo site for authentication. When the user authenticates, they are then redirected to our site with USER’s access token, and can then upload the video.

BUT, we need a solution whereby the system sends OUR permanent authentication token with the upload, so the user doesn’t have to authenticate and it’s just automatic and unseen to them.

Please help us understand the process of uploading video's directly onto Vimeo Pro servers through a Ruby on Rails application with our account’s permanent authenticatiojn token or some solution that is equivalent to this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using vimeo for video storage, or are you also going to be running a "channel" for people to view the videos on vimeo? I ask because if you are using it simply for storage (which it kind of sounds like because you are having files uploaded to your account) then there are much less expensive options.

Comment: Hi Ken. Thank for the quick reply  and help! We will be running a "channel" along with storage, so that the general public can view videos.

Comment: Do you want your channel to have all the videos that are uploaded visible all the time? It my be cheaper (and easier) to store the files using a service like AWS S3 and then curate the videos on your channel from those.

Comment: We must have all videos visible on the website at all times. We considered AWS S3 but with the transcoding service on top of data transfer & bandwidth, the cost was going to be pretty high. Any other ideas? Thanks for the help!

Comment: You should be able to authenticate once and store the token data in your database. Check this out https://github.com/matthooks/vimeo/tree/master#authentication-example-using-rails

Comment: We will have our developers try it out today. Thanks for the help Ken!

Comment: The library linked by Ken is for the old, Advanced API. This API is not going to receive any new development. The new API (https://developer.vimeo.com/api) does not yet have a ruby library, but is still pretty easy to work with. I worked with a user recently on this same issue: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vimeo-api/0sg4dz6Uvho but didn't cover upload. The library provided also uses a different upload mechanism than the new API.

Comment: Hi Dashron, Thanks for the reply. So, what is the solution? Any hints on how to do upload? Have you seen any other support threads tackling this API issue? Thanks for the help!

Comment: All of vimeo's official libraries support uploads: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/libraries. Maybe you could port from another language?